# After writing Raspberry Pi OS to SSD, I cannot add ssh file

Tags: usb, boot, pi-4, raspberry-pi-os

I am trying to boot my Raspberry pi 4b from an SSD. After following the most recent instructions I could find for allowing booting via USB (updating bootloader, setting boot order), I installed Raspberry Pi OS on the ssd with Etcher. Then I ejected the SSD and plugged it back in so that I could add the ssh file, but I got "The disk you inserted was not readable by this computer."

Tried booting the pi from it anyway but it failed (never showed up on the network).

Additional info: The SSD is branded 'Vansuny' and identifies as 'JMicron Tech Media' in disk utility. Etcher is running on a Mac. Also tried Raspberry Pi imager.

Appreciate any thoughts.

Comment: `JMicron Tech` - some jmicron USB to SSD devices simply will not boot on a pi anyway - personally, I've never had an issue with *ASMedia Technology* USB to SSD devices - cheapest ones are *ugreen* brand - just go the USB 3.0, no need for USB 3.1 as the pi won't achieve 10Gbit

Answer (score 1):

I have an RPi4 running from an SSD for almost a year now. At that time it wasn't possible to boot directly from an SSD, but it is possible to change the boot option so that the SSD will be used for /root. Perhaps that's an option for you.

If I remember correctly, I used [this page](https://www.tomshardware.com/news/boot-raspberry-pi-from-usb,39782.html) as a guide, but since then the information seem to have changed. It looks like it's now possible to boot directly from an SSD, but according to the comments it's not full proof yet.

I did the following to run my RPi4 from an SSD. It still boots from the SD card but after that only uses the SSD.

**Basic setup**

- Write an official Raspbian image to a fresh SD card.
- Copy an empty file *ssh* and (for wireless access) your *wpa_supplicant.conf* to the card.
- Boot the RPi from the SD card. It should now have an IP in your network (I use [Slitheris](https://www.komodolabs.com/ip-scanner/) to quickly identify IP's on my network) and you should be able to SSH into it with PuTTY or so.

**Prepare the SSD**

- Plug the SSD into a USB3 port of the RPi. The drive will probably be mounted as **/dev/sda1**. I'm no Linux expert at all, so not sure of that. Check with `sudo fdisk -l` and change below if necessary!
- Unmount, format and re-mount the SSD:

  `sudo umount /dev/sda1`

  `sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda1`

  `sudo mkdir /media/rootdrive`

  `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/rootdrive`
- Copy the contents of the SD card to the SSD:

  `sudo rsync -avx / /media/rootdrive`

**Change boot option**

- Add the text `root=/dev/sda1` to **/boot/cmdline.txt**. Be sure to not add carriage returns or line feeds!

  `sudo nano /boot/cmdline.txt`

After the next reboot the RPi won't run without the SSD until you remove "root=/dev/sda1" from cmdline.txt on the SD card.

So **reboot** and enjoy the speed at which the RPi now runs :)

Answer (score 0):

You're leaving out an important detail: what kind of computer are you using to insert the SD into?  Linux can read the RPI filesystem just fine, so if you're getting that error on a linux box, then the SD card is broken.  No surprise to get that error on a Windows/Mac unless you have special software to read ext2/3/4 filesystems.

How are you checking if the pi "shows up on the network"?  Is the PI connected using an ethernet cable?  Do you have an external monitor you can plug in?  That would tell you exactly how the boot process is going.

An external monitor, keyboard and mouse is pretty much a requirement for setting up a new Pi, until you have a few images ready to go.

Comment: The file system of the boot partition is `vfat` by default. He should not have any issues placing a file `ssh` there on MacOSX nor Windows. Access to the root partition is not needed.

Comment: Well, yeah, but the second partition would have an error.  It's possible that the SD card is just bad .. but the authoritative way to determine would be to boot the RPi with a monitor to see what's going on.